# Exception during execution from Internet Information Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am Working on a Website its working well when opened from Visual Studio 2008 but when opened from IIS(Internet Information Service) it gives the following error:

> Length cannot be less than zero.
>
> Parameter name: length
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot
>   be less than zero. Parameter name: length

Source Error:

```
Line 174:  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(id, 512);
Line 175:  ////append the first segment of the user's ip address to the string 
Line 176:  sb.Append(ipAddress 
                         .Substring(0, 
                                    ipAddress.IndexOf(".", 
                                                      ipAddress.IndexOf(".") + 1)));
Line 177:  ////append the users User Agent to the string 
Line 178:  sb.Append(userAgent);
```

Source File:

> d:\HiFi\HRM_Module\HRM\Global.asax    Line: 176

Stack Trace:

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than
>   zero.Parameter name: length]
>   System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32
>   length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy) +10090344
>   ASP.global_asax.CreateMAC(String id, String ipAddress, String
>   userAgent, String validationKey) in
>   d:\HiFi\HRM_Module\HRM\Global.asax:176
>   ASP.global_asax.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in d:\HiFi\HRM_Module\HRM\Global.asax:77
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

Version Information:

- Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8009;
- ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8008

Comment: Seems like `ipAddress.IndexOf` returns -1.

Comment: @L.B Any way to remove error then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you enter ***//your ipadress/website name***

i.e Like 10.11.129.233/HRM after its open from IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a local environment for hosting your website, the **Request** object returns "**::1**" as **IpAddress**, that doesnt contain "**.**"
This might be the reason of your problem.